# Undo changes to model state when angular form is canceled

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In an Angular 4 application, I have a template driven form with controls bound to values in my component. When the form input changes the object bound to the input changes immediately (two-way binding). When the cancel button is clicked, I want to undo the change to the bound object. This allows the user to change values then change their mind and cancel their changes.

https://plnkr.co/edit/RnnPwtHZY0qTN1H6er0z?p=preview

The plunker above has such a form with a bound field to read the hero.name

```
  <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
```

An input bound to a hero object.

```
  <form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>name: </label>
      <input name="heroName" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
    </div>
    <button (click)="cancel(myForm)">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
```

The cancel button calls the ngForm's resetForm() method.

```
  cancel(myForm){
    myForm.resetForm();
  }
```

#### Repro steps

1. Change the hero name; Observe the h2 changes immediately proving that the bound object changed as well
2. Click cancel; Observe the name is cleared and the h2 changes because the hero.name is now null

I expected the cancel button to change the hero.name back to the original value. Is this how resetForm() is supposed to work? Is there a different way?

Comment: Don't edit your real object. Clone it.

Answer (score 3):

If you make a reset() method, where you set the default values, then you can call it whenever it's needed, as in ngOninit and reset button click:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.reset();
  }
  reset(){
    this.hero = new Hero(1,'Plunker');
  }

  cancel(myForm){
    this.reset();
  }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/kgLDqmrTtCHAuwpfwk1O?p=preview)

You can reunite cancel() and reset() by refactoring, but you may want keep it as is in case you add something else in cancel.

Comment: If I understand this suggestion, I would have to manage some state to know what to reset the hero too.

Answer (score 3):

From the angular documentation, I guess the solution is to use a reactive form instead of a template driven form.
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms reads (emphasis :

> In keeping with the reactive paradigm, the component preserves the
>   immutability of the data model, treating it as a pure source of
>   original values. *Rather than update the data model directly, the
>   component extracts user changes* and forwards them to an external
>   component or service, which does something with them (such as saving
>   them) and returns a new data model to the component that reflects the
>   updated model state.

Comment: Given what Vega posted in the other answer, I think we can conclude that when you want to provide a cancel form button, you have to use reactive forms.